# Change the text of button on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to change the text on the button on hovering on the react button from antd design
I want to change the text on the button on hovering on the react button from antd design

```
Button
    <div className={ status == "verified" ?  `${styles.btn1} ${styles.btn1Contact}` :  `${styles.btn} ${styles.btnContact}`} >
        <Button className={ status == "verified" ?  `${styles.btnremove}` :  `${styles.btnremove1}`}
        > {status} </Button>
        </div>
```

I am doing this way

```
 &:hover {
   
  }
```

but nothing is changing

styles.btn:

```
.btn {
  display: flex !important;

 
 {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  &:hover {
  
    color: $fade-color;
  }
  &:focus {
  
    color: $fade-color;
  }
 
  }
}
```

styles.btn1:

```
.btn1 {
 
  @media only screen and (max-width: $max-size-2) {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

 
  }
}
```

styles.btn1

```
.btnremove {
  border: 0px !important;

}
```

styles.btn:

```
.btn {


  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: You can only set the `content` property on `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. You will need to change the text using javascript.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to handle that logic in your React app rather than with CSS anyway.

Comment: Either that or put two spans in the button and show/hide each on button hover.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a JS solution for your problem.
We're using a state that defaults to `false`. When hovering the Button (`onMouseEnter` is triggered), we set it to `true`. And when leaving the Button (`onMouseLeave` is triggered), we set it to `false`.

This enables us to have a value `isHovering` which holds a boolean that is `true` when hovering the button and `false` when not hovering the button. Then we only need to reference that inside our template.

When `isHovering` is `true` -> `Hovering` will be shown. If not -> `Not Hovering` will be shown.

```
const Example = () => {
  const [isHovering, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Button
      className={
        status == "verified" ? `${styles.btnremove}` : `${styles.btnremove1}`
      }
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      {isHovering ? `Hovering` : `Not Hovering`}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

And here would be a CSS (SCSS) only solution.
This behaves almost the same as the JS example. But here we render two `span` elements and display/hide them with CSS instead of having a state in our JS.

```css
.btnremove,
.btnremove1 {
  // ... your styles

  .hover-content {
    display: none;
  }

  &:hover {
    .hover-content {
      display: initial;
    }

    .default-content {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```
const Example2 = () => {
  return (
    <Button
      className={
        status == "verified" ? `${styles.btnremove}` : `${styles.btnremove1}`
      }
    >
      <span className="hover-content">Hovering</span>
      <span className="default-content">Not Hovering</span>
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Both of these solutions are accessible.

Comment: Note, that you are using Sass here, and some will not understand why it doesn't work for them when they use plain css (if they are unfamiliar with it). Please clarify your answer to mention that it is SCSS.

Comment: Would you mind explaining your JS code?

Comment: Hey, I've updated the answer to contain an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Change content with CSS in `:before` (or `:after`). Hover works only in this order **`:hover:before`**

```css
.btn:before {
  content:'Init value';
}
.btn:hover:before {
  content:'Hover value';
}
```

```html
 <button class="btn"></button>
```

Comment: btw: texts from html <button data-init = "Init"> to CSS use content: attr (data-init)